# Visual Studio 2013 C# 'FileNotFoundException'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I was currently working for a project in Visual Studio, C# Windows Form. Although my commands were running one day, the other didn't.Now i finished my project trying to test something new and it crashed all together. More specifically on the structure of the app: I have create 1 main form that has the basic characteristics that all the rest Forms inherit(like menu e.t.c). The start_form only provides Sign in and Registration which is connected to MySqlDatabase. In order to add authorization to my application i create a File with the name "authorization.txt" in which i store the id of the user when he presses the sign_in button. This code worked perfectly untilt it started throwing exceptions and prevented me to see the Design Preview of the Inherited Forms saying:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not find file
>   'C:\Users\leo\Desktop\VirtualMuseum_App\VirtualMuseum_App\authorization.txt'.

The first form (aka Sign in-Registration Form) works fine, but by the minute it tries to load the next form (aka Main Museum) it crashes, throwing the upper exception. I am giving you the code (the constructor) of the Main Museum Form below:

```
public Main_Museum()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\leo\\Desktop\\VirtualMuseum_App\\VirtualMuseum_App\\authorization.txt");
    String line = "";
    while (line != null)
    {
        line = myReader.ReadLine();
        if (line != "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show(line);
            //connection to database
            string myConnection = "datasource = 127.0.0.1; port = 3306; username = root; password = ";
            MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
            MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from virtual_museum.user where id_user = '" + line + "';", myConn);

            MySqlDataReader dr;
            myConn.Open();
            dr = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
            try
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    String firstname = dr.GetString("user_firstname");
                    Profile.Text = "Welcome" + "\n" + firstname;
                    myConn.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex){}
        }
     }
    myReader.Close();
}
```

Any Help would be deeply appreciated. I don't know what else to do.
(Note:before the whole path in the myReader, i have tried putting only the name of the file, it didn't work that either - altough in the past it did. I have no idea why is creating such a mess.)

Thanks!

Comment: use the debugger and inspect the filepath of where it's looking for the file.. do you know how to use the debugger..? also instead of using this `dr.GetString` use this `dr["yourfieldname"]`

Comment: @MethodMan, GetString is perfectly legal, and type-safe. ;-)

Comment: Sorry, but i'm new to Visual Studio. So if you could specify the steps it would be very helpful.

Comment: Do you have authorization.txt related code in your login form? If yes, can you share with us?

Answer (score 0):

The exception tells you that the file being referenced cannot be found. This will occur when A) the constructor runs, and B) there is no file at the specified path.

Without knowing further details about your application, I cannot say under which conditions B) is met. That is, you need to make sure that this file exists at the specified location.

You mention that this error appears when switching to design view. That is because the constructor will run when loading the given Form in design view. Do you make sure that the file exists when the application runs, but the file is not there when the application closes?

Either make sure the file is there while you develop the application (in addition to running it), or move the code to load the file out of the constructor.